# Why is the auxiliary 'avere', as opposed to 'essere', used when conjugating the verbs 'camminare' & 'viaggiare'?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verb

As a rule, transitive verbs in Italian use the auxiliary *avere* (*ho camminato, avrò camminato*) when conjugating in any of the compound tenses. However, *camminare* & *viaggiare* are intransitive and seem to be in the category as other verbs of motion: scendere, andare, cadere, etc. that use essere as a helping verb.

Why are these verbs exceptions to the rule?

Are there other examples of verbs that are intransitive yet use *avere* as an auxiliary verb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For intransitive verbs, unfortunately, the general rule is that «non esiste una regola che permetta di stabilire quale ausiliare debba essere usato con ciascun verbo» («there is no rule that allows to know which auxiliary verb is to be used with each verb»). There are very vague rules: you can see something about it and about a tentative 3-part classification in transitive, intransitive, “inaccusative” verbs [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-ausiliari_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), where the quotation above is taken from. However, there are *lots* of intransitive verbs to be used with *avere* as their auxiliary verb: for instance, apart from the ones you mentioned, *esagerare*, *navigare*, *riposare*, *sbandare*, *marciare*, *sorridere*...